# How to export JSON-like data in spreadsheet column to json file?

Tags: json, parsing, google-sheets, js-xlsx

I have a [Google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1saDPM9tsr2eRi6XPFmJ4zsiSJ40zOHVg4AwfFtL3LnM/edit?usp=sharing) with JSON-like data in a column and would like to export this column as a JSON file. I have tried using javascript along with xlsx package to convert the sheet to json file but it adds backslashes to the column and cannot be parsed (throws syntax error) using JSON.parse() as it does not recognise it as valid json. Any help is appreciated!
[image]

```
let xlsx = require("xlsx")
let path = require("path")
let fs = require("fs");
const inputFilePath = path.join(__dirname, './Sample.xlsx');
let File = xlsx.readFile(inputFilePath);
let content = xlsx.utils.sheet_to_json(File.Sheets['Sheet1']);
console.log(JSON.parse(content[0]["content"])); //throws error
```

Comment: Why do you need xlsx ? Can you provide a sample spreadsheet ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `I have tried using javascript along with xlsx package to convert the sheet to json file`. And also, from `it adds backslashes to the column and cannot be parsed (throws syntax error) using JSON.parse() as it does not recognise it as valid json.`, I cannot understand about your situation. I apologize for my poor English skill. In order to correctly understand about your situation, can you provide the sample value?

Comment: I have added an image of the spreadsheet for reference. I need the document to be converted to a json file. I am not being able to use the content of the second column as a json object

Comment: Thank you for replying. I noticed your replying just now. I apologize for this. From your additional sample image, unfortunately, I cannot find `backslashes` of `but it adds backslashes to the column and cannot be parsed (throws syntax error) using JSON.parse()`. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your current situation?

Comment: Try converting this excel spreadsheet to json (using npm package xlsx) and access the data inside CONTENT column using JSON.parse(). It will throw the sytnax error as it does not recognize the data as json

Comment: Thank you for replying. I noticed your replying just now. I apologize for this. From your replying, unfortunately, I cannot understand about the relationship between `Try converting this excel spreadsheet to json (using npm package xlsx) and access the data inside CONTENT column using JSON.parse(). It will throw the sytnax error as it does not recognize the data as json` and your sample image. I apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Pls, can you provide a link to your spreadsheet instead of an image ? Precise if this is an excel one or a google sheet one because you mentionned both. And the, what result do you need, a json file ?

Comment: @MikeSteelson, it is a google sheet. I want the file to be converted to json. I want to be able to access the CONTENT column data as a json object. I have added a hyperlink to the sheet in the description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example that will write the data without backslash (do not use JSON.stringify in this case). The file will be in 'test' folder here, that you have to create or change in the script.

```
// you need to activate the Advanced Drive Service (Drive Activity API).
function test() {
  var content = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange('A1').getValue();
  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("test");
  if (folders.hasNext()) {
    var folder = folders.next();
    saveData(folder, 'myJSON.json',content);
  }
}
function saveData(folder, fileName, content) {
  var children = folder.getFilesByName(fileName);
  var file = null;
  if (children.hasNext()) {
    file = children.next();
    file.setContent(content);
  } else {
    file = folder.createFile(fileName, content);
  }
}
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PWzdlaZi2m0a1xDiqLp2eJXIvx-AyvZ16CQW362q-Nw/edit?usp=sharing
Of course, replace A1 by B2 for your file.
[image]

Comment: Is there any other way that does not use Drive Activity API?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know, but I guess NO!